# javascript/jquery variable not updating from form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, variables

I have a basic web form thats using jquery to access form fields. In my javascript I have a variable for userName that I want to update and retain the value of while then letting the user submit other fields on the page.

```
var userName = "starval";
```

Then I have a function to handle updating:

```
function setName() {
    $("#setName").click(function() {
      //console.log("here");
      userName = $("#nameField")[0].value;
    });
  }
```

And the form:

```
<form>
  Name:  <input id="nameField" type="text" name="name" required>
  <input id="setName" type="submit" name="setName" value="Set Name"/>
</form>
```

I have the form ID like this as there are also other forms on the page. Checking in the javascript console of chrome shows that $("#nameField")[0].value does in fact hold whatever value is in the box. And the "here" check shows the function is being called on click of the submit button but then the userName value stays at "startval".

Comment: `userName = $("#nameField").val();` is enough

Comment: I see that is the correct approach now and I have updated my code to that syntax but it still leaves the same issue of the variable not updating.

Comment: When are you calling `setName()`?

Comment: Barmar, its in $(document).ready()

Answer (score 0):

Why not calling the val directly ? I understand you have multiples form in your page but the ID should be unique anyway.

```
userName = $("#nameField").val();
```

Comment: Ive updated my code to this but still have the problem of the value not updating.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#nameField").val();
```

You can learn more about jQuery's `val()` function here - http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you need to move this outside of function declaration:

```
$("#setName").click(function() {
  userName = $("#nameField").val();
});
```

Your `setName()` function only creates event handler for submit button click.

---

### Snippet

```js
var userName = "";

$("#setName").click(function() {
  userName = $("#nameField").val();
  showUsername();
});

function showUsername(){
  $("#username").text(userName);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Name:  
  <input id="nameField" type="text" name="name" required />
  <input id="setName" type="submit" name="setName" placeholder="Set Name"/>
</form>
<div id="username" />
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery handlers should be ideally registered when the dom is ready and HTML is loaded hence place the function inside jquery document ready as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#setName").click(function() {
      console.log("here");
      userName = $("#nameField").val();
      console.log('Username : '+userName);
    });
 });
```

Comment: I have it called in $(document).ready(function() {
        setName();
        });

Comment: Use above code don't need to create a separate function setName.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I have found a solution. It looks like the submit button was refreshing the page each time which was resetting the value to the default. Changing it to 
    Set Name 
along with including 
    event.preventDefault(); 
in my function seemed to do the trick. Thanks for the help.